# Is there an init.d start log?

Tags: centos, logs, init.d

I am experiencing a problem with an init.d script (the service won't start), so I'm wondering if a log is available so I can fix the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What script writes to what log file, depends on the script. On CentOS 6.5 if I restart `sshd` then `/var/log/secure.log` is written to, and if I restart `postfix` that goes to `/var/log/maillog`.

The easiest way to find out (instead of wading through configuration files) is IMO just to try and restart the service, and then do:

```
ls -t --full-time /var/log | head -5
```

And see if any of the top files was written to by this restart action by looking at its date info.

---

Just out of curiosity I looked to see why `postfix` writes to `/var/log/maillog`. That path is actually specified in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and maps any `mail`-related `syslog` messages there. Searching for "maillog" in files under `/etc/postfix/` gives no results, and neither does searching for `mail` there. Actually, via the [`syslog` wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog), you can find a number (2) that is used by `syslog` to log any `mail`-related messages.
So, a program doesn't have to have some path hard-coded or listed in a configuration file to be able to log under `/var/log`. Without knowledge of `syslog` and other possible logging facilities, the aforementioned method looks like a good first-try.